Third question went to Staging Ground but E-mail calls it my first question?
Background
I am new on Stack Overflow system, I joined last week and I have posted 2 questions, one of which was migrated to Stack Exchange earlier with a down-vote (not proud of it as I did not know much about it).
Today, I tried posting a new question here and it went to Staging Ground. I did some research on SG and saw some information over here and got to know that First Question goes to staging ground and the question is then reviewed by users above 500 reputation which is good for new users to understand how a question should be written.
My issue
While this was not my first question on Stack Overflow, I got an email saying 'Your first question on Stack Overflow is in the Staging Ground':

So is this a bug?

Note that the help center says "first questions" (note the "s", for the plurality).

If I recall correctly, askers are eligible to their questions coming to the Staging Ground if they have less than two successful (not exactly sure what exactly "successful" means in this context specifically) questions.

This question is similar to: I'm being routed to Staging Ground for my 2nd question. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes but in the mail it is written first question! which is incorrect. @AbdulAzizBarkat

I didn't realize it being about the E-Mail. I edited your post in an attempt to make this clearer.

I think they've assumed in the mail template that your first question in the Staging Ground is also your first question but given the current design that's not necessarily how it works (Out of all questions that qualify to go the SG only some of them do). So yeah, I'd say this can be considered a bug.

The page they reference, though, says (emphasis mine): "A “new question asker” will be guided to Staging Ground if they have asked fewer than two questions on Stack Overflow..." - notice no qualifiers about "successful" or any of the things mentioned here or here. IMHO, this page (or at least that sentence) should be more specific. It could link to Slate's answer, but that seems quite the fragmented experience.

(And I'm only suggesting that because I do feel this is about more than just the e-mail. The duplicate answers the question, technically, but the solution is to make the information more readily available in the most relevant places.)

@AaronBertrand agreed, this and directly tied to it the criteria for being able to toggle off the Ask Wizard aren't well documented, I guess that's most likely because the criteria has been changed a few times from 1 question to 2 questions then 2 successful questions and so on.

"the solution is to make the information more readily available in the most relevant places." Between this and "design flows that ensure people read the information", a huge fraction of the site's problems would conceivably be solved. (Malice and lack of English comprehension notwithstanding.)
